# why MOSFET output is oscillating like this ?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

In this circuit schematics : [image]

why this output is like this?

All voltages are dc voltage . From values , we can assume that this change is in mV or uV level.I totally don't understand whats going on here. anyone can explain .

Shouldn't be the output voltage is fixed dc ?

conditions for PMOS :

[image]

and this are the conditions for NMOS :

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the peak-peak magnitude of the oscillations? It almost looks like simulator noise

Comment: In other words, it isn't helpful to have all of the horizontal lines in your graph labeled "2.5 V".

Comment: From the parameters it looks like both mosfet are in cut-off region. Maybe the PMOS is in the triode region but doesn't seem to have any load.

Comment: @W5VO, my simulator don't show precisely the magnitude of the oscillations as you can see form the graph . but simulator noise shouldn't give a predicted graph, should it ?

Comment: @Dave , I use "Everycircuit" simulator to see output put of small circuits . Here you can't set graph labeled, it's automatic.

Comment: I've seen *real* simulators do weirder things, who knows what this toy does.

Comment: The plot you show is useless without any detail of the scale on the Y axis. Try change your SPICE integration options from TRAP to GEAR or what other non-TRAP methods you have available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost definitely simulator noise.

The NMOS has \$V_{tn}=430\$mV, while for the PMOS you have \$V_{tp}=-400\$mV.

Since \$V_{GS_n}=0\$ the NMOS is quite off, it might have some leakage current but hopefully a few tenth nano amps.

For the PMOS we have \$V_{GS_p}=-370\$mV, so the transistor is not off, nor on. This working region is called **subthreshold** region, and transistors can be (and are) used quite a lot in this region since transconductance can get very high.

Long story short, the PMOS would be more than happy to carry some drain current, but that would probably be a couple of orders of magnitude higher than the leakage current of the NMOS.

What happens then? Both transistors are working with virtually no drain current, the NMOS characteristic is a flat line where \$I_D\approx0\$ so \$V_{DS_n}\$ can theoretically be whatever voltage suits the PMOS... But that's true for the PMOS too! What happens is that the drain voltage of the transistors can be almost any voltage in the \$0\$V\$\div5\$V range. The simulator has to **guess**.

Now, simulators can be pretty darn good at guessing, really, any sort of magic happens when you run simulations, but that usually happens in transient simulations, when to make less calculations guessing which the next point will be is a good thing.

Here just about any voltage would be good, try to help the simulator adding a big resistor, some \$10^{12}\Omega\$, between the drains and some voltage, possibly ground, \$\mathrm{V_{DD}}\$ or whatever. You'll probably see the noise gone.

About the question in the comments:

> but simulator noise shouldn't give a predicted graph, should it ?

Not at all. Simulators are predictable machines built to produce predictable results. Even if some sort of randomness is needed, like in Monte Carlo sweeps, the user can decide to keep the simulation seed in order to be able to run it again in the very same conditions. There's no randomness otherwise, in other words if you feed a simulator some input data you will **always** get the same output. And that's why you see such a nice pattern, that's the simulator trying to understand what's going on, and it does so using precise mathematical tools and approximations that lead to an oscillating pattern. Just think of the various iterative methods used to approximate the solution of intersection between curves.